# It's possible to store json on amazon s3?

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-s3

I would like to store json file to my amazon s3 and then retrieve it with ajax request. Unfortunately it seems s3 does not allow content-type application/json....

I should save my file as text/plain and then add header with php?

Comment: While using content-type headers is certainly good, they are not required. If you know that a certain file contains JSON, you can just parse the response text with `JSON.parse`. In the end, a file contains either text or binary data anyway. How to process the data is a decision the client has to make.

Comment: Unfortunately after some tests it seems that the json is not well formatted if I retrieve as text/plain so I cannot parse it...

Comment: That does not have to do anything with content type. JSON **is** text. Maybe your JSON is invalid to begin with?

Comment: Probably you are right. But when I create the json, I parse and it is ok. Then I store it on s3, but when I retrieve I cannot parse it

Comment: Strange... are you sure you are actually getting any response? It could a same-origin-policy issue.

Comment: I got response and it seems a well formatted Json, I pasted it on jsonlint and it's ok. this is the json: https://s3.amazonaws.com/tropicalseo/1/prestitiinpdap.it_061313_024217.json

Comment: That does not mean you can make an *Ajax request* to it. Ajax requests are usually only allowed to the same domain, unless the external server explicitly allows such requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was parsing the json in the wrong way.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucket/myfile.json",
    type:"GET",
    success:function(data) {
            console.log(data.property)
    }
})
```

Instead this works:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucket/myfile.json",
    type:"GET",
    success:function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if(typeof obj =='object'){
            console.log(obj.property)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I think the first one magically works if the content-type is set correctly. The second one is explicitly parsing as JSON (and will probably break if you fix the content type).

Answer (score 3):

Change Metadata 'Value' in Key:Value pair to 'Application/json' from file properties, in AWS S3 console.

Comment: The key in this case is `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid parsing json use dataType property of ajax, Here we are expecting response as json so 
 `dataType: "json"` will automatically parse the json for you and can be accessed directly without JSON.parse(), in Success function body.

```
$.ajax({
        url:"https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucket/myfile.json",
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "json",    // This line will automatically parse the response as json
        success:function(data) {
            var obj = data;
            if(typeof obj =='object'){
                console.log(obj.property)
            }
        }
    })
```

> **dataType** - is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect.
>   Expecting JSON, or XML, or HTML, etc. In our case it was JSON.