# Storing JSON into Amazon S3 with Java

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to store JSON data into Amazon S3? Lets say that I want to store this JSON data:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086553/its-possible-to-store-json-on-amazon-s3%E2%80%8B) says it is possible but then it is using jQuery but I could not find the corrresponding thing in Java. Even if it is possible, in what form will the JSON be stored? Will it be dumped into a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you're pretty much dealing with bytes here so whatever format these bytes represent has no impact at all.

In your java app, convert whatever object you have into bytes then stream that out directly (or write to a file first, then upload). Sample code:

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
 byte[] bytesToWrite = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(yourObject)

 ObjectMetadata omd = new ObjectMetadata();
 omd.setContentLength(bytesToWrite.length);
 transferManager.upload(bucketName, filename, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesToWrite), omd);
```

The java client can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/

Answer (score 11):

Yes.

Just use [putObject(String bucketName, String key, String content)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), passing your JSON String for `content`.

Comment: if we call putObject method again with same key and different content then it will override old json string/content right?

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9518630/1357094)