# Store Java object to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, object, amazon-s3, upload

I have a Java object. I get this as a response from an underlying API of our system. I need to store this object in a folder inside an S3 bucket.

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41017427/9715520. However, as I said I need to upload the object in a folder inside the bucket. Is there a way I can specify the folder name as well. The example tells about saving the object to an S3 bucket. What if there are multiple folders within a bucket and one needs to store in a specific folder. Do we have something for that?

This is how I am doing it. Also is the below code sufficient enough or do I need to create s3 client explicitly to upload the object?

```
private void s3Upload(MyObject myObject) {
         
         TransferManager transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();
         
         ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
         byte[] bytesToWrite = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(myObject);

         ObjectMetadata omd = new ObjectMetadata();
         omd.setContentLength(bytesToWrite.length);
         String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
         transferManager.upload(<bucketName>, uniqueID, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesToWrite), omd);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upload an object (a PDF for example), its recommended that you use **AWS SDK for Java V2**. Using this API, you have 2 choices.

1 . You can upload an object to an Amazon S3 bucket using the **S3Client** object.

2 . You can upload an object to an Amazon S3 bucket using the **TransferManager** object.

Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. For example, if you want to store a PDF file in a folder named **folder2**, specify the name in the **objectKey**. For example:

**String objectKey =  "folder2/myPDF.pdf"**

When you ran this code, myPDF is in folder2 -- as shown in this screen shot:

[image]

If you are not familiar with using the **AWS SDK for Java V2**, refer to the [Java V2 DEV Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html) for all the concepts you need. For example, how to work with Credentials.

**S3Client**

The following code shows you how to use this object to upload content.

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class PutObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String usage = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "  <bucketName> <objectKey> <objectPath> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "  bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket to upload an object into.\n" +
                "  objectKey - The object to upload (for example, book.pdf).\n" +
                "  objectPath - The path where the file is located (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName =args[0];
        String objectKey = args[1];
        String objectPath = args[2];
        System.out.println("Putting object " + objectKey +" into bucket "+bucketName);
        System.out.println("  in bucket: " + bucketName);

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .build();

        String result = putS3Object(s3, bucketName, objectKey, objectPath);
        System.out.println("Tag information: "+result);
        s3.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.main]
    public static String putS3Object(S3Client s3,
                                     String bucketName,
                                     String objectKey,
                                     String objectPath) {

        try {

            Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
            metadata.put("x-amz-meta-myVal", "test");

            PutObjectRequest putOb = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .metadata(metadata)
                    .build();

            PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(putOb,
                    RequestBody.fromBytes(getObjectFile(objectPath)));

           return response.eTag();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }

    // Return a byte array.
    private static byte[] getObjectFile(String filePath) {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        byte[] bytesArray = null;

        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return bytesArray;
    }
    // snippet-end:[s3.java2.s3_object_upload.main]
}
```

**TransferManager object**

The following code shows you how to use this Java object to upload content to an S3 bucket.

```
package com.example.transfermanager;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.FileUpload;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.S3TransferManager;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class UploadObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "  <bucketName> <objectKey> <objectPath> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "  bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket to upload an object into.\n" +
                "  objectKey - The object to upload (for example, book.pdf).\n" +
                "  objectPath - The path where the file is located (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). \n\n" ;

       if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
       }

        long mb = 1024;
        String bucketName = args[0];
        String objectKey = args[1];
        String objectPath = args[2];


        System.out.println("Putting an object into bucket "+bucketName +" using the S3TransferManager");
        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.builder()
                .s3ClientConfiguration(cfg ->cfg.region(region)
                        .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                        .targetThroughputInGbps(20.0)
                        .minimumPartSizeInBytes(10 * mb))
                .build();

        uploadObjectTM(transferManager, bucketName, objectKey, objectPath);
        System.out.println("Object was successfully uploaded using the Transfer Manager.");
        transferManager.close();
    }

    public static void uploadObjectTM( S3TransferManager transferManager, String bucketName, String objectKey, String objectPath) {

        FileUpload upload =
                transferManager.uploadFile(u -> u.source(Paths.get(objectPath))
                        .putObjectRequest(p -> p.bucket(bucketName).key(objectKey)));
        upload.completionFuture().join();
    }
}
```

**Another Update**

Look at this line of code:

PutObjectResponse response = s3.putObject(putOb,
**RequestBody.fromBytes**(getObjectFile(objectPath)));

As long as you get your data you want to upload to a byte array, you can upload it to Amazon S3 using this code. I used a ***physical PDF file*** as an example. But if you get the byte[] from another source it still works.

The **RequestBody** supports other methods too as discussed in these Javadocs.

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/sync/RequestBody.html

Hope this clears up your doubt.

Comment: my question is more around the syntax of the API. In this case, to be specific,  I was looking for a use case wherein s3 bucket has folders within and one is interested in uploading to one of the folders

Comment: I showed you how -- specify the folder name in the objectKey. Even showed the screen shot

Comment: Ok. I didn't notice you edited. Thanks @smac2020. I got it

Comment: I also answered your question about client or transfer manager. Using V2, you can use either way - both are supported.

Comment: Yeah. This clears the doubts that I had. Thanks

Comment: However, out of curiosity, there is one parameter

objectPath - "The path where the file is located (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). \n\n" ;"

What if, as I said, it's a response from an underlying API in which case I don't have any objectPath?

Comment: In the code example, that is where you PDF is located on your local computer. For example, C:\\myPDF.pdf

Comment: So if you read my question, I am trying to upload a java object instead of a file. This object is a response from an underlying API. It doesn't have a path per se.

Comment: See my latest update about using https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/sync/RequestBody.html

Comment: saw the update. Thanks.